# How to use the model/POJO with android databinding, room and retrofit?

Tags: android, data-binding, retrofit, android-room, android-databinding

I was studying Room and Databinding in android and i showed it to my friend what i had done until that moment and than he said that my model/POJO class was not following best practices because i shouldn't be using the same model/POJO to do the requests (retrofit), save in the database (room) and do the databinding.

My model/POJO:

```
@Entity(tableName = "posts")
class Post : BaseObservable() {

@ColumnInfo(name = "idPost")
@PrimaryKey
var id: Int = 0

var userId: Int = 0

@Bindable
var message: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.message)
    }

@SerializedName("created_in")
@Bindable
var createdIn: Long = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.createdIn)
    }

@Bindable
var image: String? = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.image)
    }

}
```

When i do the request and save in the database

```
fun getPostsFromAPI(onSuccess: (posts: MutableList<Post>) -> Unit, onError: (error: Throwable) -> Unit) {

    PostsNetwork.requestPosts(
            { posts ->

                launch {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        MyApplication.database.postsDAO().insertPosts(posts)
                    }
                    onSuccess(posts)

                }
            },
            {
                onError(it)
            }
    )

}
```

With the databinding i was trying to use two way databinding.

do i have to have 3 entities for each thing (databinding, retrofit, room)? if so, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first create a domain model pojo in your domain package like in the Clean architecture and data transfer object models for retrofit, room etc in respective packages.
Then to convert objects use Mapper classes with functions that takes one object and convert to the other.